# How can i create serviсe?

Tags: c++, c++builder-6

So, i want create service. My program need work as service, but not process. I finded in Internet and edited this code :

```
#define rootkitname "myrootkit"
SC_HANDLE hSCManager;
hSCManager=OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL,SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE);
LPVTSTR rootkpath;
rootkpath="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Blocker\Project1.exe";
SC_HANDLE hManager,hService;     hService=CreateService(hManager,rootkitname,rootkitname,SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,SER    VICE_KERNEL_DRIVER, SERVICE_BOOT_START,SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,     \rootkpath,NULL,NULL,NULL, NULL,NULL,NULL);
StartService(hService,NULL,NULL);
```

This code create service, but it have mistake. In Builder6 i have this mistake:

```
[C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(60): E2451 Undefined symbol 'LPVTSTR'
[C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(60): E2379 Statement missing ;
[C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(61): E2451 Undefined symbol 'rootkpath'
[C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(63): E2206 Illegal character '\' (0x5c)
[C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(63): E2227 Extra parameter in call to  __stdcall     CreateServiceA(void *,const char *,const char *,unsigned long,unsigned     long,unsigned long,unsigned long,const char *,const char *,unsigned long     *,const char *,const char *,const char *)
```

Please, help me. Target my application is : user don't can closed my program from Task Manager.

Comment: I feel like helping you might be a bad idea. Do you have a good reason for wanting "user don't can closed my program from Task Manager"? Preferably one consistent with laws and good taste?

Comment: I want create program for school. My program it is control all work and children don't download bad program or other bad actions.

Comment: Good luck with that. Anyway, in the true C++ spirit, let's give you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot...

Comment: "My program need work as service, but not process". That won't work. A Windows service **is** a process. `GetCurrentProcessId` gives you a real Process ID etc.

Comment: Creating a service won't stop a user with sufficient rights from stopping the service in Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

`LPVTSTR` is not a thing, google suggests `LPCTSTR` (no idea if that is correct). Backslashes in C strings have to be doubled, so `rootkpath="C:\\Users\\Admin\\...`

In the call to `CreateService` - `\rootkpath` should be just `rootkpath` and remove one of the `NULL`s at the end, you have one too many.